# «Сучить коленками» — можно ли так говорить? Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, выбор-слов, словосочетания, сложное-предложение

> *После того, как едва успевшая добежать до ближайшей рощи Мария избавилась от необходимости **сучить коленками**, а заодно убедилась, что Юи — точно девочка, в чем она, конечно, не сомневалась, но все-таки... обе они повеселели и в храм решили не возвращаться.*
>   [Л. Кузнецов. Комикс про то, чего не было...](https://books.google.ee/books?id=IxVgDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT524&lpg=PT524&dq=%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=XhkYfEWquO&sig=ACfU3U1EiBGZR6ZbogHVbU5FJ9T6TACzug&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5ubDh8NrkAhWhmIsKHdEMAoIQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8&f=false)

Сначала меня заинтересовало выражение «сучить коленками». Мне кажется, что так говорить неверно. А как вы считаете?
Затем я обратила внимание на знаки. Есть «пунктуационные сомнения».
Все ли правильно? Как бы вы оформили пунктуацию в этом предложении?
[Книгу не читала — предложение попалось совершенно случайно.]

Comment: _Римма Михайлова: Как бы вы оформили пунктуацию в этом предложении?_ === Я бы добавил пару скобок: _"а заодно убедилась, что Юи — точно девочка **(в чем она, конечно, не сомневалась, но все-таки...)**, обе они повеселели и в храм решили не возвращаться"_.

Comment: Вот! Слава меня опередил! Хотел добавить в ответ в точности такое же оформление, только не успел, пришлось отвлечься.

Answer (score 1):

Чаще *сучат ногами,* но и коленками, я думаю, тоже можно сучить. Хотя примеров действительно не находится.

На [Грамоте](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x) **сучить:**

3. *чем. Разг.* Двигать попеременно взад и вперёд (обычно задевая одним о другое). *С. ножками* (о ребёнке). *С. задними лапами* (о щенке).

> Я понимаю, что деепричастный оборот надо обособить.

Так там же не деепричастный, а ***причастный*** оборот. Определяемое слово *Мария*
после него. Значит, не нужно обособления. Так ведь?

*"После того как"* я бы не стал разбивать, обычно только весь оборот отделяется, если в начале предложения.

Добавлю к ответу вариант со скобками, который позволяет поставить недостающую запятую, закрывающую оборот *"после того как",* да и вообще это замечание лучше заключить в скобки независимо от запятой (мне пришло в голову ещё до комментария Славы):

> После того как едва успевшая добежать до ближайшей рощи Мария избавилась от необходимости сучить коленками, а заодно убедилась, что Юи — точно девочка (в чём она, конечно, не сомневалась, но всё-таки...), обе они повеселели и в храм решили не возвращаться.

Comment: И-эх, конечно причастный! Спасибо, зарапортовалась. А в остальном — все ли правильно с пунктуацией?

Comment: ("После того как" я бы не стал разбивать, обычно только весь оборот отделяется, если в начале предложения.) Дописал это в ответе. На месте многоточия вообще-то должна быть запятая, но не знаю, исключает ли оно её... Совместить их, и правда, вроде нельзя.

Comment: Дело в том, что Ефремова дает немного другое значение. Сучить: 4. _разг._
Двигать взад и вперед, задевая одним за другое. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/251876 Я себе такое действо не смогла представить.

Comment: Почти то же самое. :) Не смогли? Просто коленка одна об другую трётся, насколько я понимаю.